# Include new lines within SQL VARCHAR?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

On my site, users can set a profile description which is displayed on their profile page. When they update it I want it to include line breaks.

For example, currently:

"Hey there!
My name's James :)"

Is saved as "Hey there! My name's James :)"

How can I get it to include the line breaks?

Here's my code by the way:

> ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace EG\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use EG\Models\User;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function getProfile($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        if (!$user) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('profile.index')
            ->with('user', $user);
    }

    public function getEdit()
    {
        return view('profile.edit');
    }
    public function postEdit(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'about' => 'max:250|min:2',
            'twitter' => 'alpha_dash|max:15',
            'xbl' => 'max:16',
            'psn' => 'max:16',
            'esea' => 'numeric',
            'twitch' => 'alpha_dash|max:25',
        ]);

        Auth::user()->update([
            'description' => $request->input('about'),
            'twitter' => $request->input('twitter'),
            'xbl' => $request->input('xbl'),
            'psn' => $request->input('psn'),
            'esea' => $request->input('esea'),
            'twitch' => $request->input('twitch'),
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.edit')
            ->with('info', 'Your profile has been updated!')
            ->with('info_type', 'success');
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If the data was entered in a textarea, you might already have the line breaks.  Render your data in a set of `<pre>` tags or a textarea for a better look.

Comment: how are you displaying the value? I am going to take a guess you want to do `nl2br()` on the output

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for the quick reply. When the data is set as the value paramater in a textarea it is properly formatted, but not in a <h4> tag

Comment: @Dale I'm outputting it like so: <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">About {{ $user->username }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4>{{ $user->description }}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: @Dale using nl2br() is just outputting this: Hey,<br /> <br /> I'm James!<br /> <br /> I do web things :3 without rendering the breaks

Comment: try using `{!! $user->description !!}`

Comment: @Emn1ty No luck. A I've said it's formatted fine when within a textarea but not anywhere else, thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `\n` line breaks to `<br>` using `nl2br` when you print the text in an HTML document.

For example create a function in the user model.

```
function getDescriptionHTML(){
    return nl2br($this->description);
}
```

And in the view.

```
{!! $user->getDescriptionHTML() !!}
```